# run npm run pettier:check

Tags: npm, prettier-vscode

Run npm run prettier:check

> ilearning@0.0.0 prettier:check /home/runner/work/stack-ilearning/stack-ilearning
> prettier --check src/**/*

Checking formatting...
[warn] src/pages/trisha/style.css
[warn] Code style issues found in the above file. Forgot to run Prettier?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ilearning@0.0.0 prettier:check: `prettier --check src/**/*`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ilearning@0.0.0 prettier:check script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-06-30T05_30_50_114Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

i tried to run npm prettier:check, also i format the document on vscode but still not working, i hope you can help me

Comment: Try running `prettier --write src/**/*` to fix issues in all files.